# Does ArrayList.java compile without warnings?

Tags: java, generics

Using http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html as reference

```
  111       private transient Object[] elementData;


  381       public E get(int index) {
  382           rangeCheck(index);
  383   
  384           return elementData(index);
  385       }
```

On compilation does this result in a warning like "ArrayList.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."?

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

`elementData(index)` is a method call whose return type is `E` (not to be confused with `elementData[index]` whose type is `Object`), and that method casts `elementData[index]` to `E` and suppresses the warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

Therefore the code you asked about produces no warnings.